# Is there any package for implementing hierarchical temporal memory in R?

Tags: r, hierarchical, temporal, hierarchical-temporal-memory

I am currently working on a data set in R and want to train a Hierarchical Temporal Memory on the data set, however, I am not able to find any package that supports HTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laura,
According to their [website](https://numenta.org/implementations/), they have libraries in Python, Java, C++ and Clojure. Seems there's none in R yet.
For Python there's a simple implementation here [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/numenta/nupic/blob/master/examples/NuPIC%20Walkthrough.ipynb)